# Laravel custom column, nested relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this model:

Case:

```
class Cases extends Model {
    const UPDATED_AT = 'edit_date';
    const CREATED_AT = 'crt_date';

    protected $primaryKey = 'no';
    protected $guarded = ['no'];
    protected $table = 'assist';

    public function providers() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CaseProviders', 'case_no');
    }

    public function claims() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Claim', 'reference_no');
    }

}
```

CaseProviders:

```
class CaseProviders extends Model {

    public function detail() {
        //return $this->hasOne('App\Providers', 'code', 'code')->select(['code', 'name']);
        return $this->hasOne('App\Providers', 'code', 'code');
    }

}
```

Providers:

```
class Providers extends Model {

    protected $table = 'user_cards';

    public function country() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Country','id','country');
    }


}
```

Country:

```
class Country extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'user_countries';

    public function city() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\City', 'country', 'id');
    }

}
```

City:

```
class City extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_cities';
}
```

and this code in controller:

```
$case = \App\Cases::where('no', $id)->with('providers.detail.country.city')->first();
```

Code works fine, but i not need select all column from each model. I need only this:

name,code - from detail

name - from country

name - from city.

How i can do it?

Comment: If you just want to display the required fields in a _view_, then just ignore the other fields and only echo the required fields. Why change the _model relationships_? You may need other columns elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tested this and it probably will make more queries because of the the nested relationships, but anyway, won't hurt to try it:

```
    $case = \App\Cases::where('no', $id)->with([
        'providers.detail' => function ($query){
            $query->select('name', 'code');
        },
        'providers.detail.country' => function ($query){
            $query->select('name');
        },
        'providers.detail.country.city' => function ($query){
            $query->select('name');
        },
    ])->first();
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to select only these fields with the relations you can to it directly in the model:

```
public function country() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Country','id','country')->select(['name']);
}
```

**NOTE**
You have to include the *id* column and the foreign ids columns.

Comment: Thx for answer. In mysql.log i see: select `name`, `code` from `user_cards` where `user_cards`.`code` in (21822), and then nginx crashed with 502 error :D. The same thing happens if I change model ..

Comment: Yes it worked for me and one thing to mention that I noticed is that I wrote only 'foreign ids' in select() and its working so 'id' is also not necessary. Tested in Laravel 5.5.